# Unnecessary message about MathJax loading

Tags: bug, status-completed

As I understand there were recent changes in SE engine, also MathJax version was updated. Now everytime I visit stats.SE, math.SE a message appears at the top of the page that MathJax is loading. It appears for a very short time, but it since it is on the top of the page it shifts all the page content down. So with each refresh (posted comment, clicking a link to a question) I get that page is jumping up and down. It is not a very big problem, but it is an annoying one. I use Chrome 10 on Mac OS X 10.6.6. I checked with Firefox 4, this message only appears first time you visit the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out - it'll be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: thank you for the prompt response.